# What is causing the infinite loop when using "onload" on a iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I made a simple ad system, that gets an iframe's width and displays a random ad that fits in the size.
Here is my **JavaScript**

```
function a(z) {
    var x = Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1;
    var $z = $(z);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var y = $z.attr("width");
        $z.attr("src", "/ads/" + y + "/" + x + ".html");
    });
}
```

And the **HTML**

```
<iframe onload="a(this)" width="336"></iframe>
```

The result?
In an infinite loop the `iframe` changed its `src` attribute in the following format:

- /ads/336/6.338941702168069.html
- /ads/336/5.472409646835364.html

What's wrong with it?
I expected results in the following format:

- /ads/336/1.html
- /ads/336/5.html
- /ads/336/7.html

**Snippet**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function a(z) {
    var x = Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1;
    var $z = $(z);
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var y = $z.attr("width");
      $z.attr("src", "/ads/" + y + "/" + x + ".html");
    });
  }
</script>
<iframe onload="a(this)" width="336"></iframe>
```

Comment: When iFrame loads, you call `onLoad` function. Inside it, you update the `src` attr, which will refresh the iFrame, again calling reload. This will repeat the process again and again.

Comment: Also, `Math.random()` returns a random float between `0.0` and `1.0`; you need to call `Math.floor()` on the product to get a random integer.

Comment: Use `Math.ceil(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);` instead. Or even `Math.floor` but then you could end up with a 0.

Comment: @Rajesh, so what do I need to call then?

Comment: @Stuart, you are false. The min value is 1 and floored it can not result in 0. And if I use "ceil", you never get 1.

Comment: @Rajesh, if I call `a(this)` on window.load, the value `z` in the function will be `[Window Object]`. I am using `this` to generate a different ad for all frames

Comment: Aye, i neglected to even see the + 1.